# Elasticsearch : Query on one of the fields given in the list

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch has documents indexed with the following fields:

{"id":"1", "title":"test", "locale_1_title":"locale_test"}

Given a query, following behaviour is needed at each document level:

1) If locale_1_title field is not empty(""), search only on locale_1_title field. Do not search on title field.

2) If locale_1_title field is empty, search on title field.

What can be a simple elasticsearch query to get the above behaviour ?